# Parse Bluetooth string

Tags: bluetooth

I'm developing on android with bluetooth LTE, I can send hex codes, but I send one code at time, so I need to send many informations in this way, how can I recognize a string and save the datas inside an array to parse it later?

Here is my sketch:

```
 char c=' ';
 String inString,one,check;
 char inData[11];
 char inChar;
 int counter=0;
 bool started = false;
 bool ended = false;
 byte index;

boolean NL = true;
const int LED1 = 6;
const int LED2 = 7;
const int LED3 = 2;
const int LED4 = 3;
const int LED5 = 4;
const int LED6 = 5;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("Sketch:   ");   Serial.println(__FILE__);
    Serial.print("Uploaded: ");   Serial.println(__DATE__);
    Serial.println(" ");

    BTserial.begin(9600);  
    Serial.println("BTserial started at 9600");

    pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED6, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  if (BTserial.available()>0)
    {
      Serial.print("bts: ");
      Serial.println(BTserial.available());
      c = BTserial.read();
      check =  String(c, HEX); 

      if(check=="ffbc"){
        Serial.println("check");
        index=0;
        while (BTserial.available()>0){

            inChar = BTserial.read();
            check=String(inChar,HEX);      
            if(check != "0xfff3")
            {
                inData[index] = inChar;
                index++;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<=11;i++){
          one =  String(inData[i], HEX); 
          Serial.print(i);Serial.print(": ");Serial.println(one);
        };

      }


             if(check=="ffca"){
             // Serial.write(c);
              digitalWrite(LED1, !digitalRead(LED1));
             }
             if(check=="ffcb"){
              //Serial.write(c);
              digitalWrite(LED2, !digitalRead(LED2));
              }
              if(check=="ffcc"){
              //Serial.write(c);
              digitalWrite(LED3, !digitalRead(LED3));
             }
             if(check=="ffcd"){
              //Serial.write(c);
              digitalWrite(LED4, !digitalRead(LED4));
              }
              if(check=="ffce"){
             // Serial.write(c);
              digitalWrite(LED5, !digitalRead(LED5));
             }
             if(check=="ffcf"){
             // Serial.write(c);
              digitalWrite(LED6, !digitalRead(LED6));
              }
    }
}
```

Without the loop I can read all the single datas, but for my job it's not enough, to recognize the data applications I send a "sample string" to recognize the type of informations I want to send.

Answer (score 1):

i think i solved in some way, i send always the same codes at the start and at the end of the datas, so i can racognize the end and then i parse the first element of the destination array. tell  me what you think abou, if it could help someone else:

```
 if (BTserial.available()>0)
{
  c = BTserial.read();
  check =  String(c, HEX);      
  if(check!="fff3"){              // i always start wit an fff3
  inData[index] = c;
  index++;
 }
  else if(check=="fff3"){         //end of data
  index=0;                        //reset the index for the next set of data
  if(String(inData[1], HEX)=="ffbc"){
    Serial.println("read the next 10 data of the array");
    }else if(String(inData[1], HEX)=="11"){
    Serial.println("turn on led 1");
    }

    // for more operations use a switch/case over the if

  }
```

Comment: Why are you using a string to check for the start/end data? You can simply use the hex representation: `if(c == 0xfff3)`. And I'm a bit confused, that you have a 4-digit hex code for one read operation. If you use the SoftwareSerial library as your `BTserial` object, a call of the `read()` function returns one byte at a time, so it would be a 2-digit hex code

Comment: hi, i'm using the bluetooth nativescript plugin, i don't know why but if i send a character after 9 arduino receives ffxx, (if i send 0xaa, it sends 0xffaa). when i made the first experiments i couldnt understnd the set of characters to parse, so i found the string. for the btserial i use altsoftserial